# Is it possible to compile a Flutter application to plain HTML/CSS + JS?

Tags: html, flutter

It would be really nice to have a web app written in Flutter to be output as plain HTML and CSS.

E.g. something like

```
// pseudo code

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('Some text');
  }
}
```

to become something like

```
<body>
  <div>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

so that it would be possible to access a node's properties through the DOM.

It felt like the use of the html renderer might do the trick, but I can't see a real difference on the output compared to the canvaskit renderer. Is this still possible e. g. by using very basic widgets that can be "translated" to HTML/CSS or does Flutter always use `<canvas>` to put the actual contents in when building a web application?

The ultimate goal would be, to be able to take a custom component build with Flutter and use in a non-Flutter context. Thus reading and manipulating the components state e. g. via the DOM. Some parts of the documentation read like it might be possible, but I couldn't figure it out - neither if it is possible or not.

I hope the question makes sense as I've got only little experience with Flutter and I'm trying to figure out if it would fit my needs.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If your looking into using `html` tags and stylings into your `app`, I would suggest learning `ReactJS`, since it works with tags and it is much closer to web development than flutter.

Comment: You're right, although due to various reasons I'm trying to explore alternatives to an JS-based approach, thus Flutter/Dart come into play.